# Mongoose $unwind not returning desired data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data formatted like so:

```
{
    id: "59b47f582c981415e24ffaf6",
    userName: "userName",
    email: "email",
    albums: [
        {
            _id: "59b4895b68697316e517ae2b",
            timestamp: "2017-09-10T00:37:47.409Z",
            images: [
                "https://bjnsjbnsdrjnbvolsdjb.png"
            ],
            description: "description",
            name: "name"
        },
}
```

I am trying to use $unwind  to get a nice list of just the images. The closest I have gotten is

```
{
    albums: {
        images: [ ]
    }
},
{
    albums: {
        images: [
            "https://bjnsjbnsdrjnbvolsdjb.png",
            "https://bjnsjbnsdrjnbvolsdjb.png"
        ]
    }
},
```

That was using my query like so:

```
            Profile.aggregate( [
            {$project: {"albums.images": 1, _id: 0}},
            {$unwind:"$albums"}
        ], function(err, images){
            if (err){
                reject(err)
                return
            }
            resolve(images)
        })
```

I thought I could just use {$unwind:"album.images"} but it gives me one empty array. Is there a way to write the query so it just returns a list of images?

Comment: Because you need **both** `[{ "$unwind": "$albums"},{ "$unwind": "$albums.images" }]`. `$unwind` "denormalises" the specified array. But an "array within an array" needs to be treated by it's separate paths.

Comment: @NeilLunn Golden, this works great. Thank you